# Having problems entering JSON into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to develop a system to handle data from a third party site. I will enter their data in my MySQL DB. Part of their data is a JSON string. I am new to JSON in MySQL. I have read and watched a tutorial on how to query JSON. I have done so successfully with JSON strings that I have entered. The problem is I cannot get their string to insert into my table. I get an error that says,"#3140 - Invalid JSON text: "The document root must not follow by other values." at position 11 in value for column 'ordered_shed.items'. Below is the JSON I received from the company. I have looked at it and cannot figure out what the problem is. I am using PHPMyAdmin to insert the code. The structure is.

id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
items JSON

`"lineItems":[
      { "description": "details-item-size",
        "productKey": "size",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "details-item-style",
        "model": "",
        "price": 2229,
        "productKey": "style",
        "quantity": 1,
        "value": ""
      },
      { "description": "details-item-flooring",
        "price": 0,
        "productCategory": "flooring-interior",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "details-item-floor-joist",
        "productCategory": "flooring-interior",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "details-item-roof-overhang",
        "productKey": "RoofOverhang",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "details-item-sidewall-height",
        "productKey": "wall-height",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "standard",
        "productCategory": "structure",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "Pressure Treated Skids",
        "productCategory": "structure",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "details-item-loft",
        "productCategory": "flooring-interior",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "details-item-roof-material",
        "productKey": "roof-material",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "details-item-siding-color",
        "quantity": 1,
        "productKey": "siding-color"
      },
      { "description": "details-item-siding",
        "productKey": "siding",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      { "description": "details-item-roof-color",
        "quantity": 1,
        "productKey": "roof-color"
      },
      { "description": "details-item-trim-color",
        "quantity": 1,
        "productKey": "trim-color"
      }]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you've provided is not valid. You can always check [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

 I think you just need your JSON to look like this:

```
{
    "lineItems": [{
            "description": "details-item-size",
            "productKey": "size",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-style",
            "model": "",
            "price": 2229,
            "productKey": "style",
            "quantity": 1,
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-flooring",
            "price": 0,
            "productCategory": "flooring-interior",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-floor-joist",
            "productCategory": "flooring-interior",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-roof-overhang",
            "productKey": "RoofOverhang",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-sidewall-height",
            "productKey": "wall-height",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "standard",
            "productCategory": "structure",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "Pressure Treated Skids",
            "productCategory": "structure",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-loft",
            "productCategory": "flooring-interior",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-roof-material",
            "productKey": "roof-material",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-siding-color",
            "quantity": 1,
            "productKey": "siding-color"
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-siding",
            "productKey": "siding",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-roof-color",
            "quantity": 1,
            "productKey": "roof-color"
        },
        {
            "description": "details-item-trim-color",
            "quantity": 1,
            "productKey": "trim-color"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`SELECT json_valid(<jscol>) as "isValid?"`

to check whether json column is valid. If returns 1 then it's valid. Invalid if it returns 0 (zero), and you can insert like this :

```
insert into tab(items) 
select case when json_valid(<jscol>)=1 then
                            <jscol>
       end;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=acab34a25184d8e7f3a82963957f8c20)</kbd>